# CMake & C++ - What is the best approach to share library between several git submodules

Tags: c++11, cmake, git-submodules, clion, cmake-modules

I am working with large C++ project (using cLion) which containing 4 submodules.
I wrote small C++ library which provides the ability to read from .properties file (most common in Java..).

The "Application.properties" file should includes common variables and per-project variables.
For example; I am using Elasticsearch database and all the 4 sub-modules should know his address.
In addition, Since i have 4 foreign projects i need to maintenance constantly 5 different CMakeLists files ( 4 sub-modules 1 for the main project).

My solution is to set the shared code in the main project root and using it by include the library in per project.

- The project & submodules version control is git.
  I thought about it and decided that maybe I should check for more reviews before I started writing.

With Gratitude,
Kobi.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a "common module"
for each module in my sub modules i added the following line in the cmakelists.txt file.
ADD_LIBRARY(MyLib ../Common/a.cpp ../Common/b.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyTargetName LINK_PUBLIC MyLib)

since the main repository (of the submodules) its a git repository itself.
i can manage shard library easily.
thanks.